# PingFederate OpenId/OAUTH2.0 integration with Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: security, pingfederate

Our project have a requirement to implement SSO in legacy application(Running in Weblogic) and New microservices/angular application - using PF OpenId/OAuth 2.0.

New application is using OpenId/OAuth 2.0 end point to authenticate/authorise. When I navigate to legacy application from new application , I should be able to pass the jwt token without asking for login and create user session in legacy. Also when I login first in legacy application running in Weblogic then I should be able to authenticate the user using openId/OAuth 2.0 and pass the token to new application.

Question: Is it okay to call the OpenId/OAuth 2.0 end point configured in PF from weblogic and create the user session or PF has any weblogic integration kit to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would suggest using Weblogic's OIDC functionality. Ping used to have a Weblogic integration kit, but with the addition of OAuth and OIDC to the Weblogic identity provider functionality, you're far better off using it than one of the kits.

If you don't want to use that functionality, another avenue is a WAM tool (such as Ping's PingAccess) or some functionality in a proxy like nginx or Apache in front of your application servers.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the answer. Weblogic's OIDC functionality is available only from Weblogic Version 12.xx. But we are using 10.3.6 and no plans to upgrade.  So instead of Kit or OIDC functionality, I am assuming calling the OAuth/OIDC endpoint from Controllers and retrieve token claims and create session. Would that work?

Comment: I'm not a Weblogic guru, unfortunately, Vinod... Can you add a bit more color regarding the operation you are referring to?

Comment: Dears, does anybody know any resource about Weblogic's OIDC functionality? I only find OIDC in Oracle Access Manager. Much appreciated!